# Retrieving table field when checkbox values are equal to another field

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have language table that include `LID`,`LNAME` fields in a UI.
I have many checkboxes for `LNAME`.

When the user checks some of them and submits, the system display `LID` for the checked checkbox.

My HTML:

```
<input type ="checkbox" name="language[]" vaue="English">English
```

In PHP:

```
$lang=$_POST['language'];
$sql="select LID from lqnguage where lname=$lang";
```

Please can anyone help me please I'm having trouble.

Comment: Provide your `HTML` and `PHP` code.

Comment: <input type ="checkbox" name="language[]" vaue="English">English

Comment: in php  ,   $lang=$_POST['language'];

Comment: $sql="select LID from lqnguage where lname=$lang";

Comment: I improved the English of your question and added the code you provided in comments. Next time, **edit** your question to add more details. There is a link to edit at the bottom-left.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

**PHP**

```
// This is array for language.
$l_array=array();
$l_array[1]='Gujarati';
$l_array[2]='English';
$l_array[3]='Spenish';

// Get selected languages.
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit'){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST['language']);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <?php foreach($l_array as $lid=>$lname){ ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="<?php echo $lid; ?>" /><?php echo $lname; ?><br />
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

> Now, you can get selected language_id(as key) and language_name(as value) in Array.